# spectral density of Modulated ofdm signal

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, ofdm

I have formed my OFDM symbol his length is 88
(**Nsubcarrier=72,Ncp=16**) with **Fs=1080000 Hz**

we call this symbol as **Signal_from_baseband**

I want to modulate the OFDM symbol with **Fc carrier=2.1 GHz** and plot the frequency spectrum of the modulated signal with x-axis as the frequency axis in Matlab.

Here is my tentative:

```
Ts=1/Fs;
N=88;
t=(0:N-1)*Ts;
Modulated_sig=Signal_from_baseband.*exp(j*2*pi*Fc*t)';
f=Fs*(-0.5:1/N:0.5-1/N);
Y=(1/N)*fftshift(abs(fft(y)));
stem(f,Y)
```

But the plot doesn't show a spectral density centered in Fc

Answer (score 0):

In terms of code issues, you are probably forgetting to divide by `Fs` in the exponent of the complex exponential. However, `Fs` does not appear sufficiently high compared to `Fc` and will alias. If your original signal is sampled at `Fs`, to properly display the spectrum, you will need to resample your baseband signal to a new sample rate, `Fs_new`, then divide `Fc` by `Fs_new` in the exponent of the complex exponential.